# Angular deployment in apache http

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to deploy an angular application in apache http server. To fix the 404 error on reload, I tried configuring the server as mentioned [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) but I do not know the location on htaccess file.

I did the following

1. I placed the angular app in c:/angular24/htdocs/
2. Created a htaccess file in the root of my app
3. c:/angular24/htdocs/myangularapp/
   Restarted the server and refreshing the page still does not fix the 404 error.
4. Moved the htaccess file to c:/apache24 and restarted the server and still the 404 error is not resolved.
5. Deleted the htaccess file and added the configuration in http.conf file, restarted the server and it does not fix the problem.

Can anyone please help me with what all configurations we need and location of htaccess file?

I added below in the htaccess file

RewriteEngine On # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR] RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d RewriteRule ^ - [L]

## If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html RewriteRule ^ /index.html

Comment: The `.htaccess` file should go in the same folder as your `index.html` file used to load the Angular app.

Comment: I tried that also.but it won't work.

Comment: You have to configure the httpd.conf file and change the root of your web server. Did you tried that?

Comment: No can you please explain or share some link?